# confidence intervals of estimates in mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-models, confidence-interval

I can get predicted values of a mixed model like this:

```
mod <- lmer(sales1 ~ price1 + (1|store), oranges)
X <- with(oranges, expand.grid(price1=c(30,50,70)))
X$pred <- predict(mod, newdata=X, re.form=NA)

> X
      price1      pred
    1     30 23.843916
    2     50 11.001901
    3     70 -1.840114
```

but how can I get the lower and upper confidence intervals of these three estimates?

I installed the `merTools` package and tried

```
predictInterval(mod, newdata = X, n.sims = 999)
```

but got an error

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'store' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `which` to `"fixed"` in `predictInterval` should be enough, but it isn't. So, it looks like a bug. However, along with this parameter if we supply any value for the grouping variable, everything works.

```
library(lme4)
library(merTools)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
X1 <- data.frame(Reaction = 250, Days = 4, Subject = 309)
predictInterval(fm1, newdata = X1, n.sims = 999, seed = 1)
#        fit      upr      lwr
# 1 216.8374 256.8839 181.1969
X1 <- data.frame(Reaction = 250, Days = 4, Subject = 310)
predictInterval(fm1, newdata = X1, n.sims = 999, seed = 1)
#       fit      upr      lwr
# 1 230.959 271.0055 195.3185
```

As expected, different subjects give different predictions. However, setting `which` to `"fixed"` helps:

```
X1 <- data.frame(Reaction = 250, Days = 4, Subject = 309)
predictInterval(fm1, newdata = X1, n.sims = 999, seed = 1, which = "fixed")
#        fit      upr      lwr
# 1 291.9062 328.5429 256.2472
X1 <- data.frame(Reaction = 250, Days = 4, Subject = 310)
predictInterval(fm1, newdata = X1, n.sims = 999, seed = 1, which = "fixed")
#        fit      upr      lwr
# 1 291.9062 328.5429 256.2472
```

The grouping value doesn't even have to be meaningful as it ends up being ignored:

```
X1 <- data.frame(Reaction = 250, Days = 4, Subject = -1)
predictInterval(fm1, newdata = X1, n.sims = 999, seed = 1, which = "fixed")
#        fit      upr      lwr
# 1 291.9062 328.5429 256.2472
# Warning message:
#      The following levels of Subject from newdata 
#  -- -1 -- are not in the model data. 
#      Currently, predictions for these values are based only on the 
#  fixed coefficients and the observation-level error.
```

Comment: Thanks @Julius Vainora, but I was looking for a way to predict values without having to specify the `store`. Basically I would like `predict(mod, newdata=X, re.form=NA)` to include confidence intervals for only those 3 predictions. There was a mistake in my question, I have edited it.

Comment: Thanks @Julius Vainora, that solved the problem. However the predict value from `predictInterval`, 291.9062, is not the same as with `predict(fm1,newdata=X1,re.form=NA)` which is 293.2742. Shouldn't they be the same? With `ggeffects` the predicted value is exactly the same as with `predict`.

Comment: @locus, that's due to how `predictInterval` works - it involves sampling. Set `n.sims` to something like 20000 and the prediction will be really close to the "usual" way.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/index.html) (examples, for instance, in [this package-vignette](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/marginaleffects.html)), which saves you some time because you don't need to create your data frame for `newdata`:

```
library(ggeffects)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
data("sleepstudy")
m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 + Days | Subject), data = sleepstudy)
ggpredict(m, "Days")
#> 
#> # Predicted values of Reaction 
#> # x = Days 
#> 
#>  x predicted std.error conf.low conf.high
#>  0   251.405     6.825  238.029   264.781
#>  1   261.872     6.787  248.570   275.174
#>  2   272.340     7.094  258.435   286.244
#>  3   282.807     7.705  267.705   297.909
#>  5   303.742     9.581  284.963   322.520
#>  6   314.209    10.732  293.174   335.244
#>  7   324.676    11.973  301.210   348.142
#>  9   345.611    14.629  316.939   374.283
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * Subject = 308

# example solution for the case mentioned
# in the comments...
r <- c(2,4,6)
s <- paste0("Days [", toString(sprintf("%s", r)), "]", collapse = "")

ggpredict(m, s)
#> 
#> # Predicted values of Reaction 
#> # x = Days 
#> 
#>  x predicted std.error conf.low conf.high
#>  2   272.340     7.094  258.435   286.244
#>  4   293.274     8.556  276.506   310.043
#>  6   314.209    10.732  293.174   335.244
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * Subject = 308
```

Comment: I believe this doesn't really answer the question which indeed is about predicted values for new data, not the fitted values.

Comment: It basically mimics your answer (except that not only one value is shown, but all values in the data). However,you can specify any (new) values for predictions. Examples are shown here: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/effectsatvalues.html

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, the package looks really good, but I'm not sure this is doing what I had in mind. I don't really want to have confidence intervals for every single subject, but rather for only those three estimates (I edited my question).

Comment: You can specify the values in the `terms` argument: `ggpredict(m, "price [30,50,70]")`. See also this article with examples: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/effectsatvalues.html

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that was it. However I tried to do `r <- c(2,4,6) ggpredict(m, "Days r")`, but this gives me predictions for all days. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `"Days r"` is just that this string. If you want to manipulate the string, see my edited example above. It's a bit ugly, but it works. Furthermore, this vignette-paragraph might be useful for you: https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/effectsatvalues.html#choosing-representative-values